# Setting up a hotkey in maya with python

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I was looking into making new hotkeys for some custom scripts in python and wanted to use the `pm.nameCommand` and `pm.hotkey` commands. The issue is that when I run the following code from the script editor it runs fine and everything is dandy but when I run it from a script then I get errors when trying to use the hotkey.

```
import pymel.core as pm
import toolTest

#clear existing hotkey
pm.hotkey(keyShortcut='a', ctrlModifier=True, name='')
#create named command for custom tool
#For some reason you need to run the python tool command through a python command in mel
pm.nameCommand( 'hotkeyTest', ann='Hotkey Test', c='python(\"toolTest.testing()\");')
#assign it a hotkey
pm.hotkey( keyShortcut='a', ctrlModifier=True, name='hotkeyTest')
```

here is the toolTest.py file referenced above

```
def testing():
    print "Testing Hotkeys"
```

If you run everything above in the script editor then it should work fine. Then if you put the first section of code into a file (hotkeyTest.py) and run that from the script editor you get the following error while trying to use the hotkey.

```
# Error: line 1: NameError: file <maya console> line 1: name 'toolTest' is not defined #
```

Does anyone know how to use python to set maya hotkeys for a custom tool from an external script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`mel`'s `python` function runs the code in Python's `__main__` module which doesn't have `toolTest`.

So try:

```
pm.nameCommand( 'hotkeyTest', ann='Hotkey Test', c='python("import toolTest;toolTest.testing()")')
```